# How to find the length of a string char[] in c without using a library. (Not even c standard)

Tags: arrays, c, string

I want to use no libraries at all (not even c standard) and find how long a string is in an array of characters.

Comment: You need to find the first `'\0'`. ... but *"string"* only really has meaning when you `#include` some standard libraries. "String" is not defined by the language (and when it's used in the Standard it applies to functions that need not be present in freestanding implementations) (except for string literals)

Comment: Please clarify how I can do that.

Comment: If you don't know how to do this, then you don't have sufficient experience to decide  that you don't want to use libraries.

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of counting the characters in the array before you find the first `\0`, something like:

```c
unsigned int StrLen(char *str) {
    unsigned int len = 0;
    while (*str != '\0') {
        str++;
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer you want is probably paxdiablo's, but here is another way albeit much more restricted. You can use `sizeof` for your **statically allocated** arrays.

```
char str[] = "12345";
unsigned int size = sizeof str; // will return 6: 5 +1 for null-termiantor
```

Beware that this method doesn't look for the null-terminator, instead it returns the allocated memory, so:

```
char arr[10] = { 0 };
arr[0] = 'a';
arr[1] = '\0';

unsigned int size = sizeof arr; // will return 10, not 2.
```

It also won't work with dynamically allocated arrays

```
char *arr = malloc( 5 * sizeof *arr );

unsigned int size = sizeof arr; // is the same as sizeof *char
                                // simply returns the size of a char pointer in your system.
```